# How to solve a Linear System with some known values?

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

Assuming there's a problem $K\ u=q\ $. $K$ is a (sparse) matrix with elements $K_{i,j}$  - with $i,j$ representing rows/columns and $n_i = n_j$. $u=( u_1,u_2,...,u_n)$ is the solution vector with some values of $u$ being known. How do I solve that system with Mathematica?

I assume `LinearSolve[m,b]`is not an option since it returns values for $x$ for the equation: $m.x=b$ and  the only input variables are $m$ and $b$.

My next best idea would be to simply use `Solve` - but how do I "communicate" to mathematica that some $u_i$s are known? And how do I create a really long list with variables $u_i$?

Comment: Do you know `q`?

Comment: yes, q is known

Comment: Then assuming this problem has a unique solution (`Det[K] == 0`) you can just use `LinearSolve` and there’s no need to worry about the fact that you know parts of `u`. On the other hand there might be a `Method` that allows you to provide a “guess vector” for `u` in which case you could supply those values.

Comment: Actually I realized that $q$ is not entirely known, it is unknown in the equations where $u$ is known. I'll have to figure out how to solve the equations where $u$ is unkown first, which should be possible with `LinearSolve` or `LeastSquares` and then solve the rest of the equations. btw: a system has a unique solution when `Det[K] =/= 0`

Comment: It would be helpful to have a small but complete example.

Comment: @p4di Of course. Mental goof. I still think you can just rearrange so that you can directly apply `LinearSolve` (as I believe Henrik shows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For systems of linear equations, in particular for large systems, `LinearSolve` and `LeastSquares` are the methods of choice. It is just about some preparations.

First some random data to work with. (It would have been also a good idea to present a test scenario in the first place.)

```
n = 10;
m = 4;
A0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
q = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
plist = RandomSample[1 ;; n, m];
uvals = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, m];
```

Now the strategy is as follows: Set the rows that belong to known values of `u` to the corresponding rows of the identity matrix and adjust the right hand side of the linear equation accordingly.

```
A = A0;
A[[plist]] = N@IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray][[plist]];
b = q.A0;
b[[plist]] = uvals;
u = LinearSolve[A, b];

Max[Abs[u[[plist]] - uvals]]
```

> 1.11022*10^-16

**In order to get a truely smaller system you can do the following.**

Some preparations:

```
n = 10;
m = 4;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
q = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
b = q.A;
utrue = LinearSolve[A, b];
```

Building a smaller system for solving for the remaining entries of `u` only.

```
plist = RandomSample[1 ;; n, m];
u = ConstantArray[0., Length[A]];
u[[plist]] = utrue[[plist]];
qlist = Complement[Range[Length[A]], plist];
u[[qlist]] = LinearSolve[A[[qlist, qlist]], b[[qlist]] - A[[qlist]].u];
u == utrue
```

> True

Comment: I tried your code on a very simple system with a known answer:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\2&3&6&7\\1&5&9&2\\2&2&4&4\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}3\\5\\7\\2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}17\\77\\95\\52\end{bmatrix}$$

So let's pretend like all $u_{1,2,4}$s are unknown and $u_3$ is known - I hope I'm doing nothing wrong here:

    `n = 4;
    m = 1;
    A = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 6, 7}, {1, 5, 9, 2}, {2, 2, 4, 4}};
    q = {17, 77, 95, 52};
    plist = {3};
    uvals = {7};`

Comment: With that I'm using your 2nd bit:

    `A[[plist]] = N@IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray][[plist]];
    b = q.A;
    b[[plist]] = uvals;
    u = LinearSolve[A, b];
    
    Max[Abs[u[[plist]] - uvals]]`

for u I get: `u={894., -726., 7., 100.}` which would be wrong.

Comment: Fixed a bug. Have another try.

Comment: I assume your equation is $A \cdot q=b$. Then it should be `b=A.q` as `A.q==q.A` returns `False`. With that your code works though, thanks!

Comment: You yourself brought up `b = q.A` in a comment above, so I adapted it.

Answer (score 3):

> *I assume LinearSolve[m,b] is not an option since...*

Actually, it is an option and a straightforward/convenient one at that:

```
ClearAll[m, b, k, q]
m = Array[k, {4, 4}];
b = Array[q, 4];

{u1, u2, u3, u4} = LinearSolve[m, b];
```

Assume `u2` and `u4` are known.

**Approach 1:** Use `LinearSolve` with smaller inputs:

Construct a new matrix `m1` by removing  from `m` the columns corresponding to the known variables (columns 2 and 4) a new vector `b1` by subtracting from `b` the total contribution to the totals on the lhs of the two known variables (that is, `Dot[m[[All, {2, 4}]], {u20, u40}]`), then  use `LinearSolve` with `m1` and `b1` as inputs:

```
u20 = u2 ; u40 = u4; (*known *);
m1 = m[[All, {1, 3}]];
b1 = b - Dot[m[[All, {2, 4}]], {u20, u40}];
{w1, w3} = LinearSolve[m1, b1];
```

This solution is the same as the original solution:

```
{w1, w3} - {u1, u3} // Simplify
```

> {0, 0}

**Approach 2:** Use `LinearSolve` with larger inputs adding new equations to represent what is known:

We construct a larger matrix `m2` by appending to the matrix `m` the `j`th unit vector if the variable `j` is known. In our example, we append `{0, 1, 0, 0}` for the second and `{0, 0, 0, 1}` for the fourth variables.  We also append the rhs  vector `b` with the values of known variables to get `b2`. Then we use `LinearSolve` with `m2` and `b2` as input.

```
m2 = Join[m, {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}];
b2 = Join[b, {u20, u40}];
{z1, z2, z3, z4} = LinearSolve[m2, b2];
```

This solution matches the original solution:

```
{z1, z2, z3, z4} - {u1, u2, u3, u4}  // Simplify
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0}

Comment: I ended up removing the rows of the known u values first. then I'd remove the columns of the known u's aswell and substracted them*known u's from q. it works. Short Example with $u_3$ being known:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\2&3&6&7\\1&5&9&2\\2&2&4&4\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}3\\5\\7\\2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}17\\77\\95\\52\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\2&3&7\\2&2&4\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}17\\77\\52\end{bmatrix}-7.\begin{bmatrix}1\\6\\4\end{bmatrix}$$